# Div : Show and Hide using jQuery with "Slow" option creates funny animated effects and div keep on moving up and down...

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

I have this funny problem of showing and hiding of DIV within a Div. I am trying to create user experience such that when ever the mouse hovers the main div, a small div appears with Delete and Update icons. If I use Show / Hide without "Slow" option, it works **perfectly fine** but when I use the "Slow" option, it starts appearing and hiding two times for every mouse over event even when the mouse is miles away from the main div. If the mouse stays on div then the show of appearing and disappearing will go on and on. What I have gathered so far, the mouse out event is fired when the div is displayed, now question is to how to control this? Following is my code:

Javascript:

```
function ShowCurrProblemSaveDiv(id){
    $(id).find('div').show('slow');      
 }

function HideCurrProblemSaveDiv(id){
    $(id).find('div').hide('slow');
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="PatCurrVisitProblemListDiv" 
   onMouseOver="ShowCurrProblemSaveDiv(this)" 
   onMouseOut="HideCurrProblemSaveDiv(this)">
       <div id="PatCurrVisitProblemSaveDiv" 
            style="background:red;
            display:none;">
            Delete-Update Icons
       </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I **think** your problem is that the Mouse Out is triggered when you are showing the divs, and the divs that are being shown "touches" your mouse, which will fire the onMouseOut event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/6DU4v/2/

HTML

```
<div id="PatCurrVisitProblemListDiv">
    Hi there
   <div id="PatCurrVisitProblemSaveDiv"
        style="background:red;
        display:none;">
        Delete-Update Icons
   </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#PatCurrVisitProblemListDiv").hover(function(){
    // Stops any animations on this element, and starts a new one
    // acording to which event was called - mouseover, or mouseout
    $(this).find("div").stop().toggle("slow");
});
```

As you see, I optimized it to use the least amount of code. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function ShowCurrProblemSaveDiv(id){
    $(id).find('div').stop(true, true).show('slow');      
}

function HideCurrProblemSaveDiv(id){
    $(id).find('div').stop(true, true).hide('slow');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am afraid this does not work, in fact, the Div to appear trembles like hell and the mouse needs to be placed very carefully to see the required results. Jeff was kind enough to provide a very good solution, please see the accepted answer. Thanks anyway !